# Can android app write to /sys/ without root permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

My phone's display backlight even after setting to minimum hurts me in dark. I checked the valid range of values for the file `/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness` and found it takes 0 - 255 . 0 is display off, 1 is minimum brightness, and 255 is maximum brightness.

The android system display settings when set to minimum sets the sys file value to 5 which hurts my eyes in dark. I echoed the value 1 from root terminal and it sets brighness to lowest value that makes my eyes comfortable in dark.

The sys file is owned by user `system` and group `system` and its permissions are `-rw-r--r--` .

I need my app to write to `/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness` to set the display brightness to a very minimum value. If I use `su` command in app, I can modify the file.  But I want to do the same without superuser permission. Is there some sort of permission that allows me to modify the file?

What are the possible ways to modify the /sys file without root permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need user permissions to change the screen's brightness. Just do this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams 
layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = BackLightValue;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

The variable `BackLightValue` is used to set the brightness to auto but you can change it to whatever you need

Comment: Thank you. This works only within the app, I think I need to setup `onPause()` and other methods to make it system-wide .  Also, it seems the `BackLightValue` variable is of type float. I only checked random values . And how do I use 1 - 255 integer values in float?